# Load HTML in UIWebview

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

In my app I am using a UIWebview. It has fixed height and Width. I need to load the html content in that UIWebview.

I used following code

```
self.contentWebView.scalePageToFit = Yes;
[self.contentWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```

But my problem is , If the content size too small user can not see it properly. They need to zoom it. Is there a way to fit content in my web view fully.

Answer (score 0):

First I set the scroll view and inside the scrollView I set the webView.I set the content size according to the iPhone,iPad width and height.In below code I mentioned that.I tried this for my project.It works fine.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

     CGFloat height = [[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
     CGFloat width = [[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.width"] floatValue];
     CGRect frame = webview.frame;
     frame.size.height = height;
     frame.size.width = width;
     webview.frame = frame;

     CGRect screenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds ;
     CGFloat widthForIpad = CGRectGetWidth(screenBounds)  ;
     CGFloat heightForIpad = CGRectGetHeight(screenBounds) ;
     NSLog(@"The iPad width is - %fl",widthForIpad);
     NSLog(@"The iPad height is - %fl",heightForIpad);

     CGFloat widthForIPhone = CGRectGetWidth(screenBounds)  ;
     CGFloat heightForIPhone = CGRectGetHeight(screenBounds) ;
     NSLog(@"The iPad width is - %fl",widthForIPhone);
     NSLog(@"The iPad height is - %fl",heightForIPhone);

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
       if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) //iPhone 5s
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, height+your nedded height);
       else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667) ////iPhone 6,6s,7
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(375, height+your nedded height);
       else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736)//iPhone 6s plus,7 plus
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(414, height+your nedded height);
       else{  
         //iPhone 4s
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, height+your nedded height);
       }
    }

    else{
       if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 1024){
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768, height+your needed height);
       }
       else{
       scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1024, height+your needed 
       }
    }
    int fontSize = 80;
    NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'", fontSize];
    [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
    NSString *jsWebViewFontFamilyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily = 'Helvetica'"];
   [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsWebViewFontFamilyString];
}
```

If you set the webView inside the scrollView, it works perfectly.